# Create heat map excluding 0's and highlighting double counted values in heat map fashion

Tags: microsoft-excel, heatmap

I was wondering if it is possible to create a heat map on excel, where values of 0 are excluded from the ranking, and the cells which contain the same values are highlighted in a heat map fashion?
[image]

In this case I have cells with 0 which I don't need. But I'd like cells with the same value (e.g. 0,04%) to be highlighted in green, and values of say, 0,05% in yellow and so on.

Comment: How are you highlighting the numbers currently? What version of Excel do you use?

Comment: I'm using excel version 2006. As for the heat map displayed I just went into conditional formating > heat map but it is the default scale here